# Return objects where field in child object is not present

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

*I would like to preface this with saying that english is not my mother tongue, if any of my explanations are vague or don't make sense, please let me know and I will attempt to make them clearer.*

What I'm trying to accomplish is to write a query that returns a list of objects from tblObject that do not have FieldId's between 10006 and 10009 assigned to it. With the tables below as reference only the object with Id 10056 should be returned as 10054 has all of the child objects assigned to not be seen as interesting.

To get started I used the below query, just to see if I could manage to filter out the objects that were NOT assigned to a OwnerId. I managed that, but failed to incorporate that into a query only returning the objects from tblObject.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tblExtraFieldDef
WHERE
    tblExtraFieldDef.Id BETWEEN 10006 AND 10009 AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT
            FieldId
        FROM
            tblExtraFieldData
        WHERE
            tblExtraFieldData.OwnerId = 10056 AND tblExtraFieldData.FieldId = tblExtraFieldDef.Id)
```

Table data

```
tblObject
Id      CustomerId  ParentId    Status      Nr
10054   0           10013       0           O2-10023
10056   0           10055       0           O2-10024

tblExtraFieldData
FieldId OwnerId Value               Id
10005   10054   2                   10005
10006   10054   2019-01-24T00:00:00 10006
10008   10054   2019-01-25T00:00:00 10014
10009   10054   2019-01-25T00:00:00 10015
10007   10054   2019-01-26T00:00:00 10016
10005   10056   4                   10011
10006   10056   2019-01-25T00:00:00 10012
10007   10056   2019-01-25T00:00:00 10013

tblExtraFieldDef
Id      OwnerType   Category    Name        Type    Format
10005   9           General     Per year    2
10006   9           General     Service 1   4       yyyy-MM-dd
10007   9           General     Service 2   4       yyyy-MM-dd
10008   9           General     Service 3   4       yyyy-MM-dd
10009   9           General     Service 4   4       yyyy-MM-dd
```

As Alex pointed out, I didn't make it obvious how tblObject is related to the other tables. `tblObject.Id = tlbExtraFieldData.OwnerId` and `tlbExtraFieldData.FieldId = tblExtraFieldDef.Id`

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated as this is getting quite frustrating.

Comment: It's not  clear from your description how `tblObject` is related to other tables. I have suspicion that `tblObject.id = tlbExtraFieldData.OwnerId` - am I right?

Comment: Thank you, Alex, I should've thought of adding that. I updated my post to reflect your comment.

Comment: Your description contradicts with SQL you started: "a query that returns a list of objects from tblObject" - so, it's expected `SELECT * FROM tblObject WHERE ` (possible NOT EXISTS for `tblExtraFieldData`). Why not?

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=Ph1NBA6p1J  - is it something you need?

Comment: Sadly the link does not appear to be working. It asks me to join a collab, then doesn't load anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your requirement.  You are trying to find gaps where each combination of the object ids and the definition ids do not exist within the data table.  That being the requirement, the following query statement should give you what you are looking for.

```
SELECT
  X.OBJ_ID,
  X.DEF_ID
FROM
(
  SELECT tblExtraFieldDef.ID AS DEF_ID, tblObject.ID AS OBJ_ID
  FROM tblExtraFieldDef, tblObject
  WHERE tblExtraFieldDef.ID Between 10006 And 10009
) AS X
LEFT JOIN tblExtraFieldData as DAT
  ON DAT.FieldID = X.DEF_ID and DAT.OwnerID = X.OBJ_ID
WHERE
  DAT.ID is NULL
```

The subquery in the from clause identifies all combinations of object ids and definition ids where you have an id between 10006 and 10009.  The left join allows you to find any matches and non-match combinations that exist within the data table.  Finally, the WHERE clause filters the results by looking for NULL ids.  The Null ids produced by the left join are the result of no data available for the object/definition combination.

Hope this helps … Good luck

Comment: This is very close to what I'm looking to do. The only thing I would like to change is that instead of returning OBJ_ID and all of the different DEF_IDs I'd just like a list of the unique OBJ_ID. In the end it will build a list of all the objects where the gaps are present. I will tinker myself, but if you feel like helping further then that will be greatly appreciated. Thank you so far!

Comment: In that case drop the X.DEF_ID from the select clause and add GROUP BY X.OBJ_ID after the WHERE clause.  That should give you the unique results you are looking for.

Comment: I did something similar on my own, but instead of GROUP BY I used SELECT DISTINCT. Now the only issue I'm facing is that if none of the IDs (10006 to 10009) are present, then the objects are not shown.

Comment: Try this:SELECT
  X.OBJ_ID,
  X.DEF_ID
FROM
(
  SELECT tblExtraFieldDef.ID AS DEF_ID, tblObject.ID AS OBJ_ID
  FROM tblExtraFieldDef, tblObject
  WHERE tblExtraFieldDef.ID Between 10006 And 10009
) AS X
LEFT JOIN tblExtraFieldData as DAT
  ON DAT.FieldID = X.DEF_ID and DAT.OwnerID = X.OBJ_ID
WHERE
  DAT.ID is NULL

Comment: Either I'm missing something blindingly obvious or that query is the same as the one you posted in your original answer

Comment: Sorry the previous comments was add by mistake … Try this:  "SELECT Distinct OBJ_ID FROM (<Original Query>)"  … Use the original query but omit the <> but keep ()

Comment: That did it. Thank you! I

Answer (score 0):

Literally translating problem description:

> query that returns a list of objects from tblObject that do not have FieldId's between 10006 and 10009 assigned to it.

```
SELECT * FROM tblObject O
 WHERE 
 NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT * FROM tblObjectFieldData D 
     WHERE
       O.id = D.OwnerId 
       AND D.FieldId BETWEEN 10006 and 10009
 )
```

Is it what you need?